# XML into Pins on a map

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I can get the list of Lat and Long in a list as a full string. I now need to be able to use this in the map.

Here is the code to display the map. Currently it's displaying two pins and the location. (xaml)

```
phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="BrightonHoveBuses.location"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="696" d:DesignWidth="480"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" xmlns:my="clr-  
namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps">
      <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="PinItemTemplate">
        <my:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}" 
                    MouseLeftButtonUp="Pushpin_MouseLeftButtonUp_1"
                    Content="{Binding Id}">
        </my:Pushpin>
    </DataTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="pinMyLoc"
                     TargetType="my:Pushpin">
        <Grid Height="26" 
                  Width="26"
                  Margin="-13,-13,0,0"
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="-45" />
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle Fill="Black" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"                       Margin="0"                       Stroke="White"                       VerticalAlignment="Center"                       Height="26"                       Width="26" />
            <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     Height="16" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Fill="Teal"
                     Width="16" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
          <DataTemplate x:Key="BusItemTemplate"> 
            <my:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}"  
                Name="{Binding Id}"  
                MouseLeftButtonUp="Pushpin_MouseLeftButtonUp_1"> 
    <Grid> 
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
            <Image Source="/Images/1.png" Stretch="None" Width="20" Height="25"/> 
        </StackPanel> 
    </Grid> 
</my:Pushpin> 
</DataTemplate> 
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="stops"
                     TargetType="my:Pushpin">
        <Grid Height="26" 
                  Width="26"
                  Margin="-13,-13,0,0"
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="-45" />
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle Fill="Black" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"                       Margin="0"                       Stroke="White"                       VerticalAlignment="Center"                       Height="26"                       Width="26" />
            <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     Height="16" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Fill="Yellow"
                     Width="16" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="BRIGHTON &amp; HOVE BUSES" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Stop Map" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <!-- This is the coding for the pushpins on the map-->
    <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <my:Map Name="map1" CredentialsProvider="Apg4fepCyTYEAQ0UxPKpbIljr_THidmUi7BNRth0JGtGSE0blId5FJSJqYy80kQC" Center="47.620574,-122.34942" Margin="0,139,6,99" Height="458" ZoomLevel="17" LogoVisibility="Visible" CopyrightVisibility="Visible" Loaded="startLocationButton_Click">
            <my:Pushpin Location="{Binding CurrentLocation}" Template="{StaticResource pinMyLoc}" Name="myPushPin"/>
            <my:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapPins"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Pins}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PinItemTemplate}"
            />
        </my:Map>
        <ListBox Height="87" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,603,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" >
                       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding latitude}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NaptanCode}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>


        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar Opacity="1.0" IsMenuEnabled="True" IsVisible="True">           

        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Zoom In" IconUri="/Images/add.png" Click="Buttonplus_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Zoom Out" IconUri="/Images/minus.png" Click="Buttonminus_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Me" IconUri="/Images/location.png" Click="ButtonLocation_Click" />


        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>

        <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Road View" Click="ApplicationBarRoad_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Aerial View" Click="ApplicationBarAerial_Click" />

        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>          


    </shell:ApplicationBar>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Heres the code....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Device.Location;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Platform;
namespace BrightonHoveBuses
{
public partial class location : PhoneApplicationPage
{


    public location()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = App.ViewMapModel;
        MapViewModel view = new MapViewModel();
        view.Load();
        this.DataContext = view;

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
        Uri url = new Uri("http://www.henry-edwards.co.uk/feed.txt", UriKind.Absolute);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(url);

    }
    GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;


    // Click the event handler for the “Start Location” button.
    private void startLocationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The watcher variable was previously declared as type GeoCoordinateWatcher. 
        if (watcher == null)
        {
            watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High); // using high accuracy
            watcher.MovementThreshold = 20; // use MovementThreshold to ignore noise in the signal

            watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);
            watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
        }


        watcher.Start();
    } // End of the Start button Click handler.





    public class RootContainer
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string StopName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string StopId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Stop { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string RouteId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string RouteName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string latitude { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string longitude { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Location> Location { get; set; }


    }





    void watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((App.Current as App).locsettings == false)
        {
            MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to allow this application to use information about your location?", "Use Location", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

            if (m == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                watcher.Start();
                (App.Current as App).locsettings = true;
            }
            else if (m == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
            {
                watcher.Stop();
                (App.Current as App).locsettings = false;
            }
        }
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case GeoPositionStatus.Disabled:
                // The Location Service is disabled or unsupported.
                // Check to see whether the user has disabled the Location Service.
                if (watcher.Permission == GeoPositionPermission.Denied)
                {
                    // The user has disabled the Location Service on their device.
                    MessageBox.Show("Location services must be enabled in your phone settings");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Location services must be enabled");
                }
                break;

        }
    }

    // Click the event handler for the “Start Location” button.
    private void stopLocationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        watcher.Stop();
    }


    private GeoCoordinateWatcher loc = null;


    public string stopslist;

    private void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        myPushPin.Location = e.Position.Location;
        map1.SetView(myPushPin.Location, 17.0);
        watcher.MovementThreshold = 100;
    }

    void loc_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Ready)
        {
            map1.SetView(loc.Position.Location, 17.0);
            loc.Stop();

        }
    }

    void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            if (e.Result != null)
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
                XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusExpress.ClassLibrary";
                var locations = (from n in doc.Descendants(ns + "ArrayOfStop")
                                 select new RootContainer
                                 {

                                     Location = (from s in n.Elements(ns + "Stop")
                                                 select new Location
                                                 {
                                                     latitude = s.Element(ns + "Lat").Value + " ," + s.Element(ns + "Long").Value,
                                                     // longitude = s.Element(ns + "Long").Value,


                                                 }).ToList()
                                 }).Single();

                // Do something with the list of Route Names in routeNames 
                listBox1.ItemsSource = locations.Location;
            }
        }
    }

 public class MapViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void Load()
    {

        //Do something here to populate your view collection with pins

        Pins.Add(new PinModel() { Id = 2, Name = string.Format("Pin # 2"), Location = new GeoCoordinate(39.932825, -75.168396) });

    }

    private ObservableCollection<PinModel> _pins = new ObservableCollection<PinModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<PinModel> Pins
    {
        get { return _pins; }
        set { _pins = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Pins"); }
    }

    //Event code to ensure the page updates to model changes.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private void Pushpin_MouseLeftButtonUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Pushpin pin = (Pushpin)sender;
        MessageBox.Show(pin.Content.ToString());
    }
    public class PinModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public GeoCoordinate Location { get; set; }
    }

   }

    private void ButtonLocation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loc = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
        //EventHandler for location service status changes
        loc.StatusChanged += loc_StatusChanged;
        //If the location service is disabled or not supported
        if (loc.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Disabled)
        {
            //Display a message
            MessageBox.Show("Location services must be enabled");
            return;
        }
        loc.Start();
    }

    private void Pushpin_MouseLeftButtonUp_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Pushpin pin = (Pushpin)sender;
    }

    private void Buttonminus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double zoom;
        zoom = map1.ZoomLevel;
        map1.ZoomLevel = --zoom;

    }

    private void Buttonplus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double zoom;
        zoom = map1.ZoomLevel;
        map1.ZoomLevel = ++zoom;

    }

    private void ApplicationBarRoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        map1.Mode = new RoadMode();

    }

    private void ApplicationBarAerial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        map1.Mode = new AerialMode();

    }


   }


  }
```

EDIT:

```
  public class PinModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public GeoCoordinate Location { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT:
I am trying to get all the stops on a bing map. I can get all the locations in a list, this is populated to a list box. This all works.

It's now trying to get all these locations onto the map, also with names.

So i need to do whats on the website - but on the phone - http://www.buses.co.uk/travel/live-bus-times.aspx

Comment: This should help: http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/databinding-bingmaps-control-wp7-mvvm/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure what your question is, but I think your binding with the pushpins is not working?

You have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on your ObservableCollection. That's not necessary. To make it work, you have to implement it on the PinModel and when you set the Location property than call the RaisePropertyChanged method.

Your PinModel class should look something like below to make your binding work (Allthough it's possible that your binding is working right now, because you bind it once as a whole.)

```
public class PinModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private GeoCoordinate _location;
    public GeoCoordinate Location
    {
        get
        {
            return _location;
        }
        set
        {
            _location = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Location");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    } 

}
```

Also note that het .Single() method your calling on your linq query is returning a single value instead of a list. Please have a look at the answer by Lance on how to contruct your linq query. (See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb919331%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for the .Single() documentation)

Comment: Hi, I am trying to get the list of stops, which their lat and long are produced into one list, which is the latitude. I then want all the stops to be displayed on the map. 

I have changed the pinModel, see edit...can;t see where i can put RaisePropertyChanged without it showing up as an error

Comment: Ok, oi have updated that, But the stops still don't populate on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the output of your LINQ method? It appears you are only creating one instance in your list. Try this instead of your current parsing method.

```
var locations = (from n in doc.Descendants(ns + "ArrayOfStop") 
                             select new RootContainer 
                             { 

                                 Location = (from s in n.Elements(ns + "Stop") 
                                             select new Location 
                                             { 
                                                 latitude = s.Element(ns + "Lat").Value + " ," + s.Element(ns + "Long").Value, 
                                                 // longitude = s.Element(ns + "Long").Value, 


                                             }).ToList() 
                             });
```

Comment: This all works, this outputs the locations, it's getting them as a push pin.

Comment: What appears to be happening is that all your locations is being put into a single item in your ObservableCollection. even in an output listbox it would show all the values, but it is still a single item.

Comment: Ok, how would i get them not as a single item?